# How to amend contents of javascript array - possibly using forEach function

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-tag-manager, google-datalayer

I have a function that pushes information from my site's dataLayer into an array.  I want to be able to then change the information in that array, but I am at a loss as to how to achieve this.

Here is an example of the data layer from my site's HTML:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  var dataLayer = dataLayer || [];
  dataLayer.push({
    'transactionId': 'xxx',
    'transactionAffiliation': 'xxx',
    'transactionTotal': 27.95,
    'transactionTax': 4.46,
    'transactionGoodsNet': 18.49,
    'transactionGoodsNetNoDiscount': 18.49,
    'transactionGoodsTax': 3.51,
    'transactionShipping': 5.95,
    'transactionTotal_currency': 27.95,
    'transactionTax_currency': 4.46,
    'transactionGoodsNet_currency': 18.49,
    'transactionGoodsNetNoDiscount_currency': 18.49,
    'transactionGoodsTax_currency': 3.51,
    'transactionShipping_currency': 5.95,
    'transactionExchangeRate': 1.00,
    'transactionProducts': [{
      'sku': 'sku1',
      'name': 'name1',
      'brand': 'Unbranded',
      'category': 'xxxx',
      'price': 6.00,
      'price_ex': 5.04,
      'image': 'xxx_image1.jpg',
      'url': 'url1-p2180',
      'quantity': 1
    }, {
      'sku': 'sku2',
      'name': 'name2',
      'brand': 'Unbranded',
      'category': 'xxxx',
      'price': 6.00,
      'price_ex': 5.04,
      'image': 'xxx_image2.jpg',
      'url': 'url2-p2180',
      'quantity': 1
    }, {
      'sku': 'sku3',
      'name': 'name3',
      'brand': 'Unbranded',
      'category': 'xxxx',
      'price': 5.00,
      'price_ex': 4.20,
      'image': 'xxx_image3.jpg',
      'url': 'url3-p1448',
      'quantity': 1
    }, {
      'sku': 'sku4',
      'name': 'name4',
      'brand': 'Unbranded',
      'category': 'xxxx',
      'price': 5.00,
      'price_ex': 4.20,
      'image': 'xxx_image4.jpg',
      'url': 'url4-p1448',
      'quantity': 1
    }],
    'transactionProductCount': 4,
    'transactionDiscount': 0,
    'transactionDiscountNet': 0,
    'transactionDiscountTax': 0
  });
</script>
```

I created the following javascript function to loop through the `transactionProducts` array and push all of the `url` values into an array called `productUrls`:

```js
function getProductUrls() {
  var productUrls = []
  var numberProducts = dataLayer[0].transactionProductCount
  for (var i = 0; i < numberProducts; i++) {
    productUrls.push(dataLayer[0].transactionProducts[i].url)
  }
  return productUrls
}
```

Now when I call the `getProductUrls()` function, it works as expected and pushes the values into the `productUrls` array as follows:

`['url1-p2180','url2-p2180','url3-p1448', 'url4-p1448']`

What I want to acheive is this array (preferably) - or a new array (if easier) - only containing the numbers that immediately follow the "-p" so as follows.

`['2180','2180','1448','1448']`

All of my product urls end with "-p" and then any number of digits.

I've thought about using a regular expression to replace the values `productUrls.replace(/.+\-p/g, '')`, but it doesn't work and I suspect that `replace` only works with strings and not arrays.

I suspect using a `forEach` function to regex replace each item within the array would work, but I am failing miserably in all attempts to use that.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, as I am somewhat of a javascript novice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will normally use [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to remap your values to a new array:

```
productUrls.map(v=>v.replace(/.+\-p/,''))
```

an [Array#forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) version will look like this:

```
processingUrls.forEach((v,i,a)=>a[i]=v.replace(/.+\-p/,''))
```

The callback arguments are as follows:

- *v* - is for current value
- *i* - is for value index
- *a* - an array forEach is being applied to (i.e. *processingUrls*)

thereby `a[i]=...` will replace the currently processed array element, with a new value.

Note that using `map()` is still preferable in most cases (for code style/safety reasons).

Comment: Thanks.  This worked a treat.  I mapped `productUrls` to a new array as you said `var arr = productUrls.map(v=>v.replace(/.+\-p/,''))` and I'm now able to return this new array at the end of my function.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you capture the pattern of numbers at the end.
Try this instead :

```
function getProductUrls() {
   var productUrls = []
   var numberProducts = dataLayer[0].transactionProductCount
   for (var i = 0; i < numberProducts; i++) {
     var myRegexp = /url[0-9]+\-p([0-9]+)/g;
     url  = dataLayer[0].transactionProducts[i].url;
     var match = myRegexp.exec(url);
     productUrls.push(match[1])
   }
   return productUrls
}
```

Comment: This didn't work for me at first.  First of all the `myRegexp` variable captures the example urls I gave, but the only thing that was needed were the numbers at the end, so `var myRegexp = /[0-9]+$/g` works better. Also the `var` was missing off from the `url` variable `var url  = dataLayer[0].transactionProducts[i].url`.  The final change I made was to change `productUrls.push(match[1])` to `productUrls.push(match[0])`.